# Lumen eloquent join three table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, lumen

I am new to Laravel/Lumen. I am writing some API by using Lumen. Now I need some help on join table eloquent.

Here is my table structure,

**catalog Table**

```
| id | catalog_name | about_catalog | image |
```

**product Table**

```
| id | catalog_id | category_id | product_name | image |
```

**category Table**

```
| id | category_name | about_category |
```

I have the following models

**Catalog Model**

```
class Catalog extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'catalog';

    protected $fillable = [
        'catalog_name',
        'about_catalog',
        'image'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'user_id'
    ];

    public function catagories()
    {
        return $this->hasOneThrough(Category::class, Product::class, 'catalog_id', 'id', 'id', 'category_id')->with('products');
    }
}
```

**Product Model**

```
class Product extends Model
{

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $table = 'product';

    protected $fillable = [
        'catalog_id',
        'category_id'
        'product_name',
        'image',
        'status'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'updated_at'
    ];
}
```

**Category Model**

```
class Category extends Model
{

    protected $table = "category";

    protected $fillable = [
        'category_name',
        'about_category'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'created_at',
        'updated_at'
        'laravel_through_key'
    ];

    function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'id');
    }
}
```

I need data as follows

```
  "data": [
        {
            "id": 5,
            "catalog_name": "Catalog Name"
            "about_catalog": "About Catalog",
            "image": ""
            "categories": [{
                "id": 1,
                "category_name": "Test",
                "products": [{
                              "id":1,
                              "....":"...."
                             }]
            }]
        }
    ]
```

Your help is appreciated, thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite tricky.

You can get your desired output if your relationship is like this:
Catalog has many Category,
Category has many Product

Catalog model

```
public function categories(){
  return $this->hasMany(Category::class);
}
```

Category model

```
public function products(){
  return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
}
```

On your controller you can get the data like this

```
Catalog::with('categories.products')->get();
```

In this case you should move your catalog_id to your categories table.
Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, yes that is the solution but can’t do any change in database structure. I need to achieve with this given structure only. Thanks again for your time 

Answer (score 0):

See your table structure is wrong there is no category reference in your catalog table so you can't fetch data of category you have foreign keys in product table so the data you want for that you have to **add reference of category in catalog table** then after from catalog to you can fetch **categories and then you can fetch products**
hope you understood

Comment: Thanks for answering! yes, you are right but I can’t make this change as this is using several places and that become very big.

Comment: then you have to fetch data in different way like fetch data from product table